# Running count of a character variable when a condition matches in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, cumulative-sum

I have a dataframe in which the first two columns are options that can be selected and it has a third column where the selection is noted. I'm trying to add a running count for when the selection has previously matched the first column option.

**Example Dataframe:**

```
df<-data.frame(box.1=c("A","A","B","C","A","B","A"),
                  box.2=c("B","B","A","A","C","C","C"),
                  selection=c("A","B","B","A","C","B","A"))
```

**Desired Resulting Dataframe:**

```
resulting_df<-data.frame(box.1=c("A","A","B","C","A","B","A"),
                         box.2=c("B","B","A","A","C","C","C"),
                         selection=c("A","B","B","A","C","B","A"),
                         running.count.box.1=c(0,1,0,0,1,1,1))
```

**Solution Attempt**

So far I've tried to use `group_by`, `mutate` and `cumsum` to create the new variable.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(box.1) %>% 
  mutate(running.count=cumsum(!duplicated(box.1==selection))-1)
```

The above code does not return the actual running count and changing `group_by` to `selection` or a combination of both has not had the desired results either.

Summarizing the data in not recommended as the data frame is meant to be merged with others with similar operations done to them, so the same framework should be maintained.

Is there a way to add the running count with this conditions using `dplyr`?

Thanks.

Edit: Typos.

Comment: The logic behind your running count column is still unclear for me. Can you please try and clarify how the running count should be calculated? If we group by `box.a`, I'd  expect to see a value of 2 in your running count based on what you describe, but your desired result doesn't look like that.

Comment: what is the logic?

Comment: ^, also unclear to me. Can you add more explanation around what "when the selection has previously matched the first column option" means?

Comment: @Mako212 the idea is that the running count is the number of times the option in `box1` has been selected before. so in the first row where `box.1` has option `A` and `A` is selected the running count is `0` because there's no previous data but in row two box.1 has option `A` and while it was not selected in that row it was in the previous one so the running count would be `1` in this case. Will fix the `box.a` and `box.1` typos, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(box.a) %>%
    mutate(count = pmax(0, lag(cumsum(selection == box.a)), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    ungroup()
## A tibble: 7 x 4
#  box.a box.b selection count
#  <fct> <fct> <fct>     <dbl>
#1 A     B     A             0
#2 A     B     B             1
#3 B     A     B             0
#4 C     A     A             0
#5 A     C     C             1
#6 B     C     B             1
#7 A     C     A             1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
transform(df,run = c(0,sapply(2:nrow(df),function(x)box.a[x]%in%box.a[1:(x-1)])))

  box.a box.b selection run
1     A     B         A   0
2     A     B         B   1
3     B     A         B   0
4     C     A         A   0
5     A     C         C   1
6     B     C         B   1
7     A     C         A   1
```